# Attach IAM role using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am trying to create a webserver (Ec2 instance) with an IAM role of access to S3 bucket using ccloudformation. It creates the role but doesn't attach the role to ec2-instance.

```
webserver:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: sg-webserver
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: For traffic from Internet
      GroupDescription: Security Group for demo server
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            DeleteOnTermination: "true"
            VolumeSize: "8"
            VolumeType: gp2
      ImageId: ami-0bdcc6c05dec346bf
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: key-webserver
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - Description: Primary network interface
          DeviceIndex: 0
          SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
          GroupSet:
            - Ref: webserver
  ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - Ref: S3FullAccess
  ListS3BucketsPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: ListS3BucketsPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - s3:List*
            Resource: "*"
      Roles:
        - Ref: S3FullAccess
  S3FullAccess:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
```

The yml file works fine. It creates an ec2-instance and security group but doesnot attach the IAM role to the ec2 Instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not attaching it to the EC2 resource, it should instead add it via the [IamInstanceProfile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-iaminstanceprofile) property of EC2.

The value should be `!Ref ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile`

The instance profile will never automatically attach to the instance.

```
webserver:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: sg-webserver
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: For traffic from Internet
      GroupDescription: Security Group for demo server
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            DeleteOnTermination: "true"
            VolumeSize: "8"
            VolumeType: gp2
      ImageId: ami-0bdcc6c05dec346bf
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile
      KeyName: key-webserver
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - Description: Primary network interface
          DeviceIndex: 0
          SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
          GroupSet:
            - Ref: webserver
  ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - Ref: S3FullAccess
  ListS3BucketsPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: ListS3BucketsPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - s3:List*
            Resource: "*"
      Roles:
        - Ref: S3FullAccess
  S3FullAccess:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
```

For more information over instance profiles take a look at this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html).

Comment: The stack get stuck while creating ec2 instance. It is taking to long, its not failing the resource but the status shows CREATE_IN_PROGRESS. It like 10-15 mins that I have created the stack and its still not up

Comment: Can you see anything in the EC2 console screen? Has the role successfully created and this is the only outstanding resource?

Comment: The ec2 resource is still in progress and when I navigate to the ec2 instance to view the instance there is no instance created which means it get stuck while creating the stack.

Comment: This will be an API error triggering the hanging. But the error will be caused by syntax. Can you confirm without IamInstanceProfile it is instant?

Comment: Yes I have confirmed without  `IamInstanceProfile` it gets initiated normally without IAM role attach to it

Comment: Updated my template, oops pretty sure the value should be `!Ref ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile`

Comment: Did this help @Shifa?

Answer (score 1):

The missing piece is the `IamInstanceProfile` parameter to `EC2Instance`. That should reference the instance profile ARN. Add the following to `EC2Instance`:

```
IamInstanceProfile: !GetAtt ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile.Arn
```

Comment: If I added to ec2 instance properties it shows an error `Template error: resource ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile does not support attribute type arn in Fn::GetAtt`

Comment: @Shifa updated answer. `Arn` was supposed to be capitalized

Comment: The stack get stuck while creating ec2 instance. It is taking to long, its not failing the resource but the status shows `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS`. It like 10-15 mins that I have created the stack and its still not up